# How to launch another application from one application without installing

Tags: java, android, android-studio

There is a button to launch other application inside my application and i use intent getpackagename. I manage to call and launch the other application but need to install the application inside phone before it can launch. Is there any other way to make the application launch without installing it or this seem impossible to do it?

Comment: You can create an intent to a Play Store page to an app that implements [instant app](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this solution -

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.myapp");

if(intent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null){  //Open app if installed
    startActivity(intent);
}else{//Send to play store to download or instant app solution
try {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.example.myapp")));
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.myapp")));
}
}
```

you can replace download from play store code with instant app launch code if that app supports it as [@jake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9688781/jake) stated [How to launch another application from one application without installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58350691/how-to-launch-another-application-from-one-application-without-installing#comment103055898_58350691).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question...if the application that i would launch does not support instant app, is it means the app should be install anyway using method that you provide above?

Comment: Yes. it is the only way for now :) @nuratiqa